# Powerbi service RLS

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-embedded

RLS for users of the same organisation to see each others data but not another organisation's data in powerbi. I have tried dynamic rls and my model has a many to many relationship so it is returning all the data or no data at all.

Comment: Well it works if you build you RLS rules correctly, but there's no details to say more.  Note that it's often better to build separate models for each target organization.